# Match over a concatenation of a whole column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to collect only the rows which are different between two tables.

The PK are the first two columns.

How can I fix this formula? I guess I use `V:W` incorrectly.

```
=if(Q11&" "&R11="","", isnumber(match(Q11&" "&R11, V:W,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Off the bat: yes, MATCH is used incorrectly, the 2nd argument should be a one-dimension array, can't be two columns. Can you please share a sample spreadsheet with some of the data shown in your image? Having a starting point makes it much easier to provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you have 'today' data in column B
And 'last time' data in column C

And you want to get values that exist only in 'today' column but not in 'last time'.

You can use:

```
=query(
ArrayFormula(
if(countif(C2:C,B2:B)=0,
    B2:B,
    ""
)),
"select Col1 where Col1 <> ''"
)
```

As you use more columns in your datatable, you can concatenate and use for example: C2:C&" "&D2:D&" "&E2:E instead of one column.

Comment: Can I please ask for a brief explanation?

Comment: Can I please ask for a brief explanation? This means: if current cell in C appears somewhere is col B, then return "". Else run the query `select Col1 where Col1 <> ''`